# gem pg, 'libpq-fe.h header' and Heroku push error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I followed tutorials and created (via `rails new`) three seemingly identical rails apps. The first two can launch via `rails server` locally or `heroku open` without any problem. The third one--also generated via `rails new`--can launch locally (via `rails server`), but not with `heroku open`. After much reading, I concluded it had to do with the gem 'pg', but why is this not an issue with the other two apps? I even copied over the Gemfile from one of the "successful" apps to see if I could get the third app to work on Heroku (no go). Any insight is greatly appreciated!

So here's the `bundle install` result:

```
Using rake 12.3.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 1.1.0
Using minitest 5.11.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using activesupport 5.2.1
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubi 1.7.1
Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
Using nokogiri 1.8.4
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.4
Using loofah 2.2.2
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
Using actionview 5.2.1
Using rack 2.0.5
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using actionpack 5.2.1
Using nio4r 2.3.1
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
Using websocket-driver 0.7.0
Using actioncable 5.2.1
Using globalid 0.4.1
Using activejob 5.2.1
Using mini_mime 1.0.0
Using mail 2.7.0
Using actionmailer 5.2.1
Using activemodel 5.2.1
Using arel 9.0.0
Using activerecord 5.2.1
Using mimemagic 0.3.2
Using marcel 0.3.2
Using activestorage 5.2.1
Using public_suffix 3.0.2
Using addressable 2.5.2
Using io-like 0.3.0
Using archive-zip 0.11.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using autoprefixer-rails 9.1.0
Using coderay 1.1.2
Using better_errors 2.4.0
Using bindex 0.5.0
Using msgpack 1.2.4
Using bootsnap 1.3.1
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Using ffi 1.9.25
Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using sass 3.5.7
Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
Using bundler 1.16.3
Using byebug 10.0.2
Using xpath 3.1.0
Using capybara 3.5.1
Using childprocess 0.9.0
Using chromedriver-helper 1.2.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using method_source 0.9.0
Using thor 0.20.0
Using railties 5.2.1
Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
Using multipart-post 2.0.0
Using faraday 0.15.2
Using multi_json 1.13.1
Using gibbon 3.2.0
Using high_voltage 3.1.0
Using jbuilder 2.7.0
Using jquery-rails 4.3.3
Using ruby_dep 1.5.0
Using listen 3.1.5
Using sprockets 3.7.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Using rails 5.2.1
Using minitest-spec-rails 5.4.0
Fetching pg 0.20.0
Installing pg 0.20.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/new-laptop/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pg-0.20.0/ext
/Users/new-laptop/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180808-7108-inkyrf.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/new-laptop/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/new-laptop/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.5.0-static/pg-0.20.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/new-laptop/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pg-0.20.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/new-laptop/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.5.0-static/pg-0.20.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.20.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.20.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  pg
```

And here's the `mkmf.log` log:

```
New-Laptop:toy_app new-laptop$ cat  /Users/new-laptop/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.5.0-static/pg-0.20.0/mkmf.log
find_executable: checking for pg_config... -------------------- no

--------------------

find_header: checking for libpq-fe.h... -------------------- no

"clang -o conftest -I/Users/new-laptop/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17 -I/Users/new-laptop/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/new-laptop/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -I/Users/new-laptop/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32  -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/new-laptop/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib -L. -L/Users/new-laptop/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib     -lruby.2.5.1-static -framework Foundation  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"clang -E -I/Users/new-laptop/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17 -I/Users/new-laptop/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/new-laptop/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -I/Users/new-laptop/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32  -pipe  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: 'libpq-fe.h' file not found
#include <libpq-fe.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
/* end */
```

Comment: probably pg version old, try to use 1.0.0 version. `gem 'pg'` then `bundle update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like PostgreSQL is not installed on your computer. Install PostgreSQL first (for example via homebrew):

```
brew install postgresql
```

Then bundle again:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Postgresql is not installed--will it cause issues with sqlite?

Comment: Also: What led me to asking this question is: Why do the other apps work and not this one?

Comment: This app is obviously depending on the `pg` gem that needs PostgreSQL installed on your machine. Or at least the `pg` gem is in your Gemfile. Will it cause issues with SQLite? No, both work fine on the same machine. Why do other apps work without PostgreSQL? They probably do not have a dependency to `pg` defined in their Gemfile.

Comment: "Dependency" is the part I need to understand. So now I know what to look into. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres.app to run your dbs, see https://coderwall.com/p/279aqg/install-pg-gem-with-postgres-app

> gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/**my-version**/bin/pg_config

Comment: I tried this one, I get the pg with the version I need, 1.2.3, but the folder doesn't contain all files i need. It seems incomplete. I am using Win 10. Is there any solution for this problem please, thank you.